# Why does GetCurrentProcess return -1?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

In this small program, why does `GetCurrentProcess()` return -1?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    HANDLE h = GetCurrentProcess(); // ret -1 
    printf("0x%x\n",(DWORD)h); 
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong?

In `Kernel32.GetCurrentProcess` I see this:

```
OR EAX,FFFFFFFF  ; EAX - ?
RETN
```

Comment: It's a self-referential special case. You can get the actual `HANDLE` representing your process if you need it for some reason (perhaps for IPC) by using `OpenProcess (...)`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is correct, see [this API reference for GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179.aspx).

> The `GetCurrentProcess` function retrieves a pseudo-handle for the current process, which is currently defined as `(HANDLE)-1`. However, because you should not assume that the value will never change, the `GetCurrentProcess` function is provided as an alternative to hard-coding the constant into your code.

Answer (score 8):

`-1` is the pseudo-handle that represents the current process. It's normal.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with -1 value. It will indicate current process handle. You can refer remark section in [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It's meaningless if you try to communicate this handle across process boundaries, so there is something wrong depending on how you look at it. In process A it refers to process A, if you pass it to process B it refers to process B. Real (non-negative) handles do not have these properties, and when passed from process A to B continue to reference their original process.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman pseudo-handles are not inheritable, so you can't pass it another process.